# How do I best approach a multiple-target binary classification in Tensorflow/Keras?

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow, binary-classification

I currently have eight features which are either categorical or continuous variables. My targets are many (~1000) binary variables. So far I have attempted skmultilearn and sklearn.multioutput. I would like some help on developing a tensorflow model, or if its even possible. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you would use for that is "multilabel classification".

It is certainly possible to do so in Tensorflow, although I would say it is more frequent to see it in examples of image classification rather than tabular data.

They key to this kind of task is that the final unnormalized log-probabilities (logits) go through a sigmoid layer, and then the binary cross-entropy is used as loss function.

[Here](https://github.com/ashrefm/multi-label-soft-f1/blob/master/Multi-Label%20Image%20Classification%20in%20TensorFlow%202.0.ipynb) you can find a complete example.

As a side note, when implementing it, you can compute both the sigmoid and the loss together with [tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits).

Comment: Thanks @noe! I will try this ASAP. Your example is focused on classification of images. Are there any major differences in the way the model is setup when features are more typical, like numerical or strings?

Comment: While the last layers are typically Dense for any model, the initial layers vary wildly between networks meant for different kinds of data. For tabular data, you will normally find dense layers from beginning to end (with appropriate activation functions), while for text you would normally find LSTM or self-attention layers.